# Proteger perguntas, quem, quando e porquê?

Tags: debate, privilégios

A bem pouco tempo ganhei o privilegio [Proteger Perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions).

Estava agora aqui a olhar para uma pergunta e achei que deveria ser protegida. Mas fiquei na dúvida, será que protejo? Será que não?

Afinal, quais são os critérios para proteger perguntas?

- Quem é que pode/deve proteger uma pergunta?
- Quando é que se deve proteger uma pergunta?
- Porque devo proteger uma pergunta?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Moderadores e usuários com pelo menos 15000 pontos (3500 no beta) de reputação podem proteger perguntas. Além disto o sistema pode fazê-lo se identificar um padrão que mostre que a pergunta é algo de respostas de baixa qualidade escritas por usuário novatos.
- Perguntas devem ser protegidas quando atraem muitos usuários que ainda não conhecem a forma de uso do *site* e respondem a pergunta popular de forma ingênua. É raro precisar fazer isto. O ideal é não proteger porque aconteceu um caso. Muito menos porque acha que vai acontecer. É raro acertar sem subsídios que indicam que há um problema e pode causar mais mal do que bem. Na dúvida não protege, peça ajuda.
- Normalmente são perguntas que se destacam em buscas e são muito fáceis de dar uma resposta sem substância. O novo usuário é voluntarioso e quer dar sua opinião ou colocar qualquer coisa que provavelmente já foi postada antes de uma forma melhor, ele quer participar não importa como. Normalmente as respostas não acrescentam nada ao que já foi respondido. Por incrível que pareça isto evita muita postagem inútil.

Na verdade na maioria dos casos o mecanismo do site ([Comunidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade)) protege o que deve ser protegido e não precisa da intervenção de usuários e moderadores.

Comment: A pergunta é esta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4553/desenvolvimento-de-apps-para-android-quais-as-ferramentas-e-linguagem-para-inic

Comment: Parece-me que deveria ser protegida. No entanto, só aconteceu um caso.

Comment: Acho que este caso foi aleatório. Não foi por causa desta pergunta, poderia ter sido qualquer outra. Ele não sabia como perguntar. Acho que é um caso diferente do usuário que esfrega as mãos e diz "oba, eu sei o que responder, cheguei e já posso participar desse fórum novo que achei". Para estes casos só protegendo todas as perguntas :) É caso para sinalizar e remover.

Comment: sim isso já fiz, mas a pergunta parece encaixar numa pergunta a ser protegida. Apesar de ainda não haver nenhum indicio, não parece?

Comment: Até pode ser sim, mas não vi motivo ainda. Eu sei que dá coceira de usar o novo poder :) Só parecer não é um bom motivo para proteger.

Comment: Por acaso não é mesmo nada isso. Nem liguei nenhuma ao "novo poder" :)  
Só achei mesmo que devia estar protegida. Por isso é que fiz aqui a pergunta. Mas, tendo de haver motivo, concordo que não faça sentido proteger. A única pergunta que fica é: Proteger por precaução ou só por motivo óbvio?

Comment: Só motivo óbvio. O ideal é ter zero perguntas protegidas.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação :)

Comment: Esse é o privilégio mais besta do site. Você chega em 15k, comemora o privilégio, e depois percebe que não serve para (quase) nada.

Comment: Esta [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146007/2541) surgiu na fila e ao editar as tags vi a opção de proteger, lembrei então que tinha esse privilégio. O estranho, e talvez por isso eu ter esquecido, é que a opção não aparece em outras perguntas. Tinha entendido que os requisitos eram 15k e pergunta ter mais de um dia. Houve alguma alteração ou eu entendi mal?

Comment: @ramaral não sei qual critério adicional deve ser cumprido.

Comment: Tem de haver algum que não é referido em [proteger perguntas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions). De qualquer forma nunca me surgiu situação em que precisasse usar.

Comment: Aqui também não tem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765/140010. De fato no site todo não vi um caso pra usar mesmo. Até onde eu usei acho que não estava causando problema. É para ser usado em casos bem exagerados, o que só deve ocorrer no SO. Não é porque teve um caso que deve proteger.

Comment: Talvez seja um critério, baseado num daqueles complicados algoritmos "à Stack", que de alguma forma limita as perguntas elegíveis a serem protegidas.:) Se for, acho bem.

Comment: @ramaral Sem entrar em detalhes, a proteção existe pra perguntas que estejam recebendo "não-respostas de usuários novos" então se uma pergunta não tem "não-respostas de usuários novos", não tem porque ser protegida

Comment: Exemplo http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118183/101 o sistema funciona

Comment: @bigown engraçado que ela está protegida pelo zekk que eu ainda não sei quem era ;)